# How can I make the font size bigger without making the parent input element bigger?

Tags: html, css

I wan't to be able to make the font size bigger on this text box, without making the text box bigger, any help? :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/91pon.jpg, my code for the CSS is down below, it that's any help. (box is the class of the form holding the elements)

```
.box input[type = 'text'], .box input[type = 'password'] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    margin: 40px auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid #70abff;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    width: 400px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans MT';
    background: #191919;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CSS` is respecting your padding rules and keeping the proportions consistent with your instructions. To prevent the box from growing, you'd have to set a fixed height and remove the padding rules.

```css
.box input[type='text'],
.box input[type='password'] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid #70abff;
  /*   padding: 28px 20px; */  /* <-- removed */
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;                /* <-- fixed height */
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT';
  background: #191919;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.box.larger input[type='text'],
.box.larget input[type='password'] {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" value="something">
</div>

<div class="box larger">
  <input type="text" value="something">
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tLf0kog/)

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to achieve a specific height, it is important to specify all the components of the height. You are specifying `padding` and `border`, but not `font-size` or `line-height`.

Overall height is `border` + `padding` + `line-height`. `font-size` will control the actual size of the text and should be less than or equal to `line-height`.

Your original input was roughly 80px tall:

- 16px line-height
- 56px padding
- 8px border

We can reallocate that without changing the overall height:

- 8px for top + bottom border
- 24px for line-height (example)
- 48px remaining for padding

```css
input[type='text'] {

  
  /* new/modified code */

  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 24px 20px;

  /* other properties */

  background: none;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid #70abff;
  width: 400px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT';
  background: #191919;
}
```

```html
<input type=text value="Sample Text Value">
```